# Does shared memory changed in the parent process affect child processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

A shared memory array (multiprocessing.Array object) is sent to a process as an argument. If the parent process changes the shared memory, does the child process see the changes? And can the parent process see changes made by the child-processes?

If not, in what way can I change the shared memory using data from a queue the child processes fill up? I thought about using another process, but it seems redundant.

The documentation on this seems to be scarce...

Platform is windows 8

Comment: What is the specific platform/version/etc..?
Props to dckrooney for edits to OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes.

The example shows an Array being modified in a child process and the changes being visible in the parent process (and a Value as well).

Comment: Yes it turned out I had a bug - two numpy arrays were added and I expected the same instance returned...